# Can't install DotNetNuke (DNN) Development Project Templates on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to create a DNN project in my Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9.19), like described in https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155422/visual-studio-2017-development-templates-for-dnn-dotnetnuke

When I'm searching for "Dotnetnuke" in Marketplace I've no results.

[image]

If I try to install the vsix file downloaded from https://github.com/ChrisHammond/DNNTemplates/releases/tag/v09.01.00
I got this error:

[image]

Any kind of solution/advice will be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe try the V9 release from GitHub? Perhaps my 9.1 release had something screwed up for 2017? Not sure.

Comment: Thanks Chris for you reply. I've already solve it. I opened in my VS the solution placed in VSIX folder of Source code (.zip), downloded from Git, and after that was immediately asked to install the DNN extensions.